# EventStore: Event does not exist for stream:

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb, event-store

`.net 7`.

Application written in `CQRS+ES`. Application create bunch of events lets say `TenantCreated`. These events create streams in event store like `Tenant-0`, `Tenant-1` etc.

Problem when start application starts send a lot of events to `EventStore 23.10.0-jammy` (1K), the first created stream is not `Tenant-1` but `Tenant-1483864`. When application started inscenarion when only 10 Tenants created - no problems at all. When application started in debug mode  with breakpoints(works slowly) - no problem at all.

I understand that the problem may lie in application code. But the strange thing if you click on this spirit stream `Tenant-1483864` in event store UI, you will see message saying there is no event:
[image]

but if you click on JSON link in `stream browser` you will see event:[image]

What is the magic number 1483864 ?
In despite of the problem may be in business logic, why for the same stream event store says `no event` and on the same time it shows event if you click on `JSON` ?

Comment: Would be easier to understand the issue if you added some code that does what you described.